# How to check user url back redirection in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I want to check if user redirect back to certain url in laravel ?
can anyone have any idea how to get it ?
like this below for example ?

```
if(redirect()->back()){
 //
}
```

Comment: You may redirect back with [session](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/redirects#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data) and check its existence wherever you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect this with session parameter.

For example;

```
public function my_function() {
    //your codes here
    if($success) {
        return redirect()->route('homepage')->with('back', '0');
    } else {
        return back()->with('back', '1');
    }
}
```

Then you can control on your page with 'session()'.

For example;

views > login.blade.php

```
@if(session('back') and session('back') == 1)
    You are return back!
@else
    Welcome, you are here first time.
@endif
```

And if you want to send this information on a form you can use this;

```
<form>
    <!-- your other input -->
    <input type="hidden" name="back" value="{{session('back')}}">
</form>
```